# Using TextCases to identify prepositions

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation, text, linguistics

```
Clear["Global`*"];

prepositions1 = 
  TextCases[WordList[], "Preposition"] /. {} -> Nothing // Flatten // 
   Union;
prepositions1a = 
  TextCases[#, "Preposition"] & /@ WordList[] /. {} -> Nothing // 
    Flatten // Union;
```

The two syntaxes above check if a word is a preposition (or so I think).

Then I checked every word in the dictionary using `WordData` for `PartOfSpeech`:

```
prepositions2 = 
  If[MemberQ[WordData[ToLowerCase[#], "PartsOfSpeech"], 
      "Preposition"], #, Nothing] & /@ WordList[];
```

Finally I generated enough prepositions using `RandomWord` such that the result didn't change after applying `Union`. This seems like a recognizable list.

```
prepositions3 = RandomWord["Preposition", 1000] // Union
```

> {"a", "abaft", "aboard", "about", "above", "across", "after", 
> "against", "along", "alongside", "amid", "amidst", "among", 
> "amongst", "anent", "around", "as", "aslant", "astraddle", "astride",
> \ "at", "athwart", "atop", "bar", "barring", "bating", "before", 
> "behind", "below", "beneath", "beside", "besides", "between", 
> "betwixt", "beyond", "but", "by", "circa", "concerning", 
> "considering", "contra", "despite", "down", "during", "ere", "ex", 
> "except", "excepting", "failing", "fer", "for", "fore", "forth", 
> "from", "in", "inside", "into", "lacking", "less", "like", "mid", 
> "midst", "minus", "near", "neath", "next", "nigh", "notwithstanding",
> \ "o'er", "of", "off", "on", "onto", "opposite", "out", "outshout", 
> "outside", "outwith", "over", "pace", "past", "pending", "per", 
> "plus", "pro", "qua", "re", "reference", "regarding", "respecting", 
> "round", "roundabout", "sans", "save", "saving", "since", "sine", 
> "than", "through", "throughout", "thru", "thwart", "till", "to", 
> "touching", "toward", "towards", "under", "underneath", "unless", 
> "unlike", "until", "unto", "up", "upon", "versus", "via", "vice", 
> "wanting", "while", "with", "withal", "within", "without"}

```
Length /@ {prepositions1, prepositions1a, prepositions2, 
  prepositions3}
```

> {394, 394, 124, 124}

Try: `Select[StringContainsQ["ist"]][prepositions1]` to see what has made its way into the `prepositions1` list.

**Question(s)**

How can I use `TextCases` to identify prepositions (or another part of speech) properly? Since I didn't get any warnings, I want to ask if `TextCases` is intended to be used like this.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really an answer, but rather a comment.

I believe `TextCases` is meant to operate on whole sentences instead of individual words, and probably relies on neural networks.

Consider finding `"Preposition"`s on The Origin Of Species:

```
TextCases[ExampleData[{"Text", "OriginOfSpecies"}], "Preposition"] // 
     ToLowerCase // Tally // ReverseSortBy@Last // Take[#, 20] & // TableForm
```

$$
\begin{array}{cc}
 \text{of} & 7269 \\
 \text{in} & 3904 \\
 \text{to} & 3560 \\
 \text{that} & 1772 \\
 \text{as} & 1436 \\
 \text{by} & 1322 \\
 \text{on} & 1239 \\
 \text{from} & 1118 \\
 \text{for} & 1109 \\
 \text{with} & 973 \\
 \text{at} & 680 \\
 \text{if} & 415 \\
 \text{than} & 371 \\
 \text{between} & 329 \\
 \text{under} & 221 \\
 \text{during} & 214 \\
 \text{into} & 199 \\
 \text{though} & 183 \\
 \text{within} & 104 \\
 \text{whether} & 102 \\
\end{array}
$$

Also, `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"` may affect results. At least it drastically affects performance...

Comment: Everyone gets performance issues. Even Mathematica.

Comment: Thanks @kirma for your effort and the answer. I will wait for half a day to see if there is more activity on this. I thought prepositions in a language were fixed but since I am not a linguist, I can't say for sure. Why would someone need AI for this!